# WebSocket returning 403 every time

Tags: go, gorilla

---

I'm not sure why this error keeps occurring but when I try connecting in my web browser it fails and returns 403, but it doesn't make sense since no where in my code I specifically told it to return 403, and no middleware is involved, I attached a picture of the error im getting. Im also using Gorilla websocket with gin, here is my code that hosts it

```
func WebsocketServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, context *gin.Context) {
    fmt.Println("connection received")
    var upgrader2 = websocket.Upgrader{
        CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
            return true
        },
        EnableCompression: false,
    }
    db, err := aws.GetDB()
    if err != nil {
        helpers.Log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()
    c, err := upgrader2.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        helpers.Log.Println(err)
        return
    }

}
```

```
func PublicRoutes(c *gin.RouterGroup) {
    c.GET("/ws", func(c *gin.Context) {
        relay.WebsocketServer(c.Writer, c.Request, c)
    })
}
```

Im using aws to host this, is it a hosting issue?

`[GIN] 2023/05/07 - 22:18:49 | 403 |      18.344µs |  71.121.188.229 | GET      "/ws"`

Comment: The current code looks good to me. Since the request can reach the gin server, I would assume there is not hosting issue. The name of the func `PublicRoutes` implies that it's public. Maybe it's not public actually? Can you show how the full router is configured?

Comment: Determine whether `connection received` is printed to standard output.  If it's not, then the problem is before `WebsocketServer` is called.

Comment: Its not being printed at all, it just returns 403

Comment: The PublicRoutes is public, it is just a standard routing group

`public := router.Group("/")
 routes.PublicRoutes(public)
`

Comment: If `connection received` is not printed to standard output, then function `WebsocketServer` is not called.  We cannot determine why the handler is not called from the information in the question.

Comment: Dose `router` use any middleware? Please note that the middlewares for `router` affect `public` too.

Comment: I mentioned previously there is no middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is no longer a problem, it seemed to be an issue with my CORS? I fixed it by moving the configuration to the bottom. I should've put this code in my intial question

Before

```
router := gin.Default()
config2 := cors.DefaultConfig()
    config2.AllowOrigins = []string{"http://localhost:3000", "https://rblxfortune.vercel.app", "https://bloxbet.click", "http://localhost:80"}
    config2.AllowCredentials = true
    router.Use(cors.New(config2))

    HandleRoutes(router)
    public := router.Group("/")
    routes.PublicRoutes(public)
    router.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
        http.Redirect(c.Writer, c.Request, "/login", http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })
    private := router.Group("/")
    private.Use(helpers.AuthRequired)
    routes.PrivateRoutes(private)
    
    err := router.Run(config.Port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

After

```
router := gin.Default()

    HandleRoutes(router)
    public := router.Group("/")
    routes.PublicRoutes(public)
    router.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
        http.Redirect(c.Writer, c.Request, "/login", http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })
    private := router.Group("/")
    private.Use(helpers.AuthRequired)
    routes.PrivateRoutes(private)
    config2 := cors.DefaultConfig()
    config2.AllowOrigins = []string{"http://localhost:3000", "https://rblxfortune.vercel.app", "https://bloxbet.click", "http://localhost:80"}
    config2.AllowCredentials = true
    router.Use(cors.New(config2))
    err := router.Run(config.Port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
```